# Are there hidden, machine-dependent parameters for SciPy's optimize.least_squares?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using `scipy.optimize.least_squares` (Python 2.7, SciPy 1.0.0) to solve a least squares problem with 10 independent variables and a residuals vector of length ~60 (the code runs a system of ODEs using the independent variables as parameters, and compares the output to experimental data points).  When I run the same code on two different machines (Mac and Linux), I get different results for the optimum values of the independent variables.  While I have no reason to believe that there is a unique minimum to this problem, I expected that identical code would give identical results on different machines.

In my code, I have explicitly specified all 19 arguments of `least_squares`, with each set to the default values (so, `method='trf'`) except for `diff_step`, which I have set manually.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), this is the only argument that depends on the machine, so by setting its value, I thought the runs on different machines would be identical.

I have observed the dynamics of the independent variable vector while `least_squares` runs and seen that the first ~10 steps (as the initial values are stepped to construct the jacobian) are indeed identical between the machines (and conform to the `diff_step` values that I set), but once a step is taken away from the initial independent variable vector, the two machines diverge.

Are there some hidden machine-dependent parameters which could lead to this behavior? And, if so, is there a way I can control these to obtain identical results on the two machines?

UPDATE: Both systems are 64-bit.  I'm not sure how to check the BLAS/LAPACK usage (much less the flags I used on compilation).  On the mac, I ran

```
>>> np.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
...
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
...
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

But when I ran it on the linux machine, I got `NOT AVAILABLE` under each category.

Comment: By any chance is one system 32 bit and the other 64 bit?

Comment: Wild guess: BLAS/Lapack differences? Multithreading activated / deactivated within those. (and +1 for 32-bit/64-bit guess)

Comment: Your Mac seems to use [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate). Linux does not have that and needs some other BLAS implementation.